# How to select an element that must have more than one css class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-selectors

I have an element that has two classes at all times:

```
<p class="general_description laptop">
<p class="images laptop">
<p class="specs laptop">
```

One class describes the item (**laptop**) and the other (**general_description, images, specs**) describes the state that the page needs to be in to present one of three types of information about the item.

**How can I show or hide the `<p>` element only if both classes in my selector are present?**

For example, if I only want to show the `<p>` element that corresponds to both the `specs` and `laptop` classes, I have tried doing this but it does not work:

```
$(".specs .laptop").show();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$(".specs.laptop").show();

OR

you could use the `is()` function in jquery. it takes a selector and tells you if the element conforms to it:

```
$(".specs").is(".laptop"); //returns true if the element has the laptop class
```

Comment: It will definitely work. It is a standard CSS 2 selector that has been fully supported by jQuery for, almost, ever.

Answer (score 1):

IIRC, it is:

```
$(".specs").filter(".laptop").show()
```

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the space between the class names.

```
$(".specs.laptop").show();
```

Reference: [jQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/class#classclass)

Comment: Thx, I never realize this statement.